# VirtualBox Installing Guest Additions Not Allowing Full Screen Mode

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox, fullscreen, guest-additions

I'm running a Windows 8.1 VM in Virtualbox on OSX. I want my Windows 8.1 to be able to display full screen but of course to do so you have to install guest additions. Which I then did, but after multiple reboots I'm still not able to view my VM in fullscreen. Just a lot of black around the edges.

OS X: El Capitan v10.11.5

Virtualbox: v5.0.20 r106931

Windows: 8.1

Anyone have some ideas of what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a macbook whose native resolution was 1440x900, trying all the things you did, and seeing the same results, until I found and enabled 2D and 3D hardware acceleration in my virtual machine's settings (Windows 10, in my case). Starting the VM again, I then got full native resolution in full screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this type of issues with older Gen devices.

- May be this some bug but for me
  when I got this issue I used scaled mode then switched to full screen mode it worked for me.

> Try to experiment different graphics VboxVGA, VboxSVGA and other
> options one will enable Full screen Mode

- If you have enabled recording kindly disable and check.
- If you installed guest-additions properly you should see vbox icon in desktop tray if not kindly reinstall guest-additions with Admin rights.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).